# Aligning h1 classes inside of a div id

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align certain  classes so that "left" aligns to the left part of #header, "links" aligns in the center, and "right" aligns to the right of #header. I would also like to have the icons align with the text in #header vertically.

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/uhd9h9o6/

```
#header{
    width:90%;
    height:60px;
    margin: 20 auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.left{
    color:#000;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:24px;
    position:relative;
    width:220px;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
    margin-left:1.5%;
    height:50px;

}

.right{
    color:#000;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:22px;
    position:relative;
    width:90px;
    display:block;
    z-index:2;
    margin-right:2.5%;
    height:50px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.links{
    color:#000;
    float:left;
    font-size:24px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding:0px;

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You know we cant see your local image here. And can you please explain with more detail. Or sample picture would also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsfiddle example is using `.left` and `text-align:center` and same for `.right` as well.

Instead of using `text-align` you can use width according to each element in your header block.

Example:

```
--------------------------------------
|             |        |             |
| header-left | center | header-right|
|             |        |             | 
--------------------------------------
width:33%       33%        33%
```

Depending upon no. of elements, Something like [css grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Better option, you can use bootstrap-grid.

Comment: haha, i just actually did this on my own! much appreciated though.